# Integration Microsoft Access in Oracle Apex

Tags: ms-access-2010, oracle-apex

Could you please tell me how can I connect Oracle Apex on the cloud with Microsoft Access which is running on an end user's laptop?

Comment: You're likely going to have to provide a whole lot more information (network topology, what you've tried, what errors you're getting).  Architecturally, that sounds really, really weird.  Having a cloud-based application act as the client for a server sitting on a laptop would be supremely unusual.  Possible assuming the laptop has a static IP, it's VPN'd in to your corporate network (I assume a corporate network here), and several firewalls are configured correctly.  But I'd strongly suspect you'd want a different architectural approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: APEX doesn't really *do* connections to other databases directly. It is designed to *replace* Access with Oracle, not extend it. For APEX to access it at all, your Access DB would need to have something like its own REST microservices, for example, or support a DB Link from the Oracle DB to Access. MS Access just isn't really designed to support that sort of enterprise-level access. I also agree with Justin: your described architecture is *bizarre* to say the least. It seems very unstable at a minimum (Access needs rock-solid networking) and potentially very insecure.